# Pyomo - extract bound value from matrix depending on two variables

Tags: python, pyomo

In a abstract model I have a variable (`model.s[t,x,y,z]`) whose upper and lower bounds are defined by functions (let's say `f(a,b)` and `g(a,b)`) depending on the value of two other variables (`model.a[t,x,y,z]`,`model.b[t,x,y,z]`).

So let's say I have a discretization over the two input variables (`model.a_discr[i]`,`model.b_discr[j]`)and I have the value of the bounds (`model.s_upper_bound_value[i,j]`,`model.s_lower_bound_value[i,j]`) on these points. These discretizations are not changing with the indices. The three variable are continuous and indexed over different sets (time,space).

How do I extract for each index value the relevant bound?

I thought about using piecewise but I couldn't succeed. I think that there should be a way using binary variables but I'm still having trouble.
Do you have any suggestion about that?

Thanks

Comment: I don't quite follow exactly what you're trying to do, but I would suggest that you encode the fact that `model.s` upper and lower bounds depend on two other variables as constraints rather than trying to set it as a variable bound, if you are not doing so already.

Comment: Yes I was trying to write them as piecewise constraint using the `piecewise_nd` function in the package but couldn't figure out the way to insert the indices.